# any step by step simple procedure to move magento from wamp local to live server

Tags: magento-1.7, mysql, server, wamp

I have developed my store on wampserver local now i want to place my Magento store on live server and i want to know step by step procedure. please guide me that what is better approach
approach1= add all products on local then migrate on live server
approach2= add all products after putting store on live server

Answer (score 1):

@david: Here is solution.

1. Take backup the magento mysql database
2. Transfer all magento files(means bakup of your magento file)
   3.adjust magento configration: for tht go to app/etc/local.xml file and change all information regarding database.
3. Restore magento databsae: for that go to magento database and find table name, The table you should edit is core_config_data and the values you need to change are in the path column. Change the web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url to match the new domain name by altering the value column for both records.

Last don't forget to delete var/cache and vat/session.

Answer (score 0):

kashif khan,  i suggest to upload  first to local then  live.

```
1.Check Product is working or not at local then it is ok then upload to live.
2.if you have any issue then solved the products at local then upload product at live correctly
```

**Issue:** I suggest  `don't upload product image at local`  because if upload t

```
his also need upload image at live
```

Comment: everything including products extensions are working on local. currently i have a single product in store which is working

Comment: i cannot understand?